# Typeerror for componentRef in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a beginner in ReactJS and wanting to print a particular div content within the site. From what I have read, the "react-to-print" package should help me for this use case. I have followed several tutorial but I met with an error where I am trying to assign `componentRef` with `useRef()`

This is what I have right now

```js
import React, { createRef, forwardRef, useRef, useState } from "react"
import Barcode from "../barcode/Barcode"
import { Button, Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, ModalFooter } from 'reactstrap'
import PrintButton from '../buttons/PrintButton'
import ReactToPrint, { PrintContextConsumer, useReactToPrint } from "react-to-print"
import { WindowScrollController } from "@fullcalendar/core"


const PrintModal = forwardRef((props) => {
    const [basicModal, setBasicModal] = useState(false)
    console.log("data", props)
    const componentRef = useRef()
    console.log("componentRef", componentRef)

    const handlePrint = useReactToPrint({

        content: () => componentRef.current,
        onafterprint: () => console.log("PRINT BERHASIL")
    })

    return (
        
        <div className='demo-inline-spacing'>
            <div className='basic-modal'>
                <Button color='primary' onClick={() => setBasicModal(!basicModal)}>
                    Print
                </Button>
                <Modal isOpen={basicModal} toggle={() => setBasicModal(!basicModal)}>
                    <ModalHeader toggle={() => setBasicModal(!basicModal)}>Print</ModalHeader>
                    <ModalBody>
                    <div ref={el => (componentRef=el)}>
                        /** The content that I want to Print **/
                    </div>
                    </ModalBody>
                    <ModalFooter>
                        <Button color='primary' onClick={handlePrint}>
                            Print
                        </Button>
                    </ModalFooter>
                </Modal>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
)

export default PrintModal
```

When I open the modal, it gives me the error like this `Uncaught TypeError: invalid assignment to const 'componentRef'`

Where did I go wrong and how should I fix this?

Comment: _`componentRef=el`_  the issue is here. Did you mean to use `componentRef.current = el`?

Comment: Ah that is indeed where i did wrong! Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Try this way, since it is a functional component it should work.

```
div ref={componentRef}>
   /** The content that I want to Print **/
</div
```